# how to get the debug information for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I write a DOM tree protecter Chrome extension to examine if the DOM tree changes. I have the js files in background_page, how can i get those console.logs() in other test html files? What I can only find now is the debug information of chrome://extensions/ when i click on generated_background_page.html. So how can I get information of other webpages? Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I have found very useful when debugging chrome extensions is to use the "inspect element" feature of the chrome developer tools. If you have a page or an element (such as on a popup from your extension) that you want to debug:

```
Open up Developer Tools
Wait for your popup to appear (if its not already up)
Switch to the Elements view on Developer Tools
Click the magnifying glass at the bottom so you can select an element
Click on an element in the page you want to debug (e.g. the popup page)
```

Now your Sources view and other views line up to match the element you've clicked on. The console will now let you look at variables in that context.

If you are not able to get the extension to work, there could be a whole host of reasons.

1. Are all your scripts loaded form the extension's directory or are you serving
   them from a site? Chrome will not load scripts from an external site
   unless over https AND after the site that is serving the script has
   been whitelisted. See the [Chrome Content Security
   Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)
   for more info.
2. To inspect the DOM, you need to inject a content script into the page that is being loaded. Are you sure you are doing this correctly? The manifest.json must be done right or else your [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) will not get loaded.
3. For your content script and extension to communicate, you must post and receive messages. More information is [available here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication).

Perhaps the best suggestion I have is that you follow the [Chrome extension "tutorial"](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) carefully until you have something working and then amend it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it's not the problem in the element tag. What i wanna find out is something in the Console tag. There's some output if i click on the generated_background_page.html, it's the debug info of the page chrome://extensions/. I wanna let it show some console logs of websites or local pages in the console tag.

Comment: I don't understand, so some more clarification/information will be useful.
1) When you say "console tag", do you mean the console tab of the chrome developer tools (i.e., debugger)? 
2) Are you looking at a chrome extensions behavior while on the chrome://extensions/ page?
3) What does console log of a website or local page mean?

Comment: 1)Oh it's a typo, it's the console tab that outputs. 2) The extension i am making can only let console.logs() of the only page chrome://extensions/ comes out in dev tools' console tab. I want this console.logs() of other pages. I wrote a function of traversing DOM tree and print the name of the node out, I can only get the HTML0 HEAD1 BODY2 SCRIPT3 one, which is of that setting page. I want get other webpages DOM trees and print it out.

Comment: Okay. So it looks like you want to write a chrome extension and have it print out the DOM tree of a web page. Your current extension can do this for the chrome://extensions page, but cannot do this for other web pages. Do I have these right?

Comment: Yep, you got it! There is no output when i open a new tab and entered website like google.com. window.addEventListener('load', function() {...}); and document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {...}); are the main 2 functions, but it prints nothing for other pages.

Comment: Thanks i ll check it out. It's all in local folder, I plant JSs in background pages, is it better to put it into content script? I didn't use sendMessage, i guess problem lies here.

Comment: Well, your content script that you inject into the page that is loaded is different from your background page's script. Think of it this way. You have a web page that you want to inspect with your extension. Your extension's background.js (and related scripts) can manipulate the DOM of the loaded page, but only through a content script that is injected into the page. The injected content script and the background script communicate through window.sendMessage.